# Как добавить ожидание загрузки всего контента python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

У меня есть парсер, отслеживающий контент на одном сайте. Проблема в том, что основной контент на главной странице подгружается асинхронно в течение ещё секунд 15-ти, но requsts в  python уже возвращает мне результат, естественно с пустым массивом необходимых мне данных.

К примеру код:

```
page = requests.get(path_to_site, timeout=30)
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(page_soup.find_all(class_='css-r7wjyo'))
```

возвращает в консоли `[ ]`

Есть какая-то возможность исправить ситуацию?

Comment: в таких ситуациях спасает только selenium

Comment: Иногда помогает анализ трафика.